# Calling web api PUT FromBody "value" always null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to call the ValuesController WebApi controller (that gets created by default) "PUT" method using cURL. No matter what I do, send value="abc", "abc" or "=abc" as I saw suggested in other questions for the POST method, to no avail.

```
        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }
```

I also tried changing the Content-Type to application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded, nothing seems to work.

```
curl -H -d "=TEST" -X PUT  http://localhost:30960/api/values/5
```

Is this a bug in ASP.NET 5 Web Api or is there a different format I need to use when calling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make it work you need to pass it as a simple string:

```
"any value here"
```

There is even a [test](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e985fa5d423968f36a651a354d9c953192c52532/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Test/JsonInputFormatterTest.cs#L69) for this behaviour

Remember to add an `application/json` Content-Type header when issuing a request.

I've just tested it for both PUT and POST requests.

Using curl it's:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "'Test'" -X PUT http://localhost:[port]/api/values/5
```

Comment: Are you able to call it with cURL?

Comment: You're probably missing quotes in body string. See update

Comment: @mbudnik - can I use same curl as above but with Content-Type application/xml - d "'Test'" -X POST url to receive simple string at OWIN controller defined as [HttpPost] public string PostReceive ([FromBody] string data) eventually I want to send valid XML but should be able to send simple string with this I would think?

Comment: @mbudnik - doesn't work I just tried it -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "'test'" -X POST url does not work -  [FromBody] string data is NULL?

Answer (score 2):

If you are posting data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then you need to remove the `FromBody` attribute. This is a change in behavior from MVC5/WebAPI2.

If you are posting data as `application/json` or xml, then you need the `FromBody` and *the parameter must be some bindable 'DTO' type having named properties matching your posted field names*.

For instance to post `{ "Name" : "James"}` your action must have signature

```
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]DtoType value)
```

and definition

```
public class DtoType
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

instead of signature

```
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
```

(Instead of defining DtoTypes you can also use dictionary access, with any of `dynamic`, or `Newtonsoft JObject`, or `Dictionary<string,object>` but then you lose your strong typing and property name intellisense)

Comment: I just want to be able to call the Put method as it comes from the template, with the signature shown in the question.